# Especificar última linha para preenchimento de formulário - VBA

Tags: vba, formulário, macro

Estou fazendo um formulário e quero que a pessoa cadastre somente 6x (somente 6 linhas) o conteúdo. Como limitar essa quantidade ?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Conforme exemplo acima, eu coloquei as linhas e colunas e quando vou preenchendo o formulário, novos numeros vao descendo

```
    Private Sub CmdSalvar_Click()
Dim Linha As Integer

'Valor inicial da Variável Linha
Linha = 85

**Do Until ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CADASTRO").Cells(Linha, 8).Value = Empty
    Linha = Linha + 1**

Loop
'SE o usuário não entrar com os dados
If TxtMes.Value = Empty Or TxtAno.Value = Empty Then
    ElseIf TxtLeitura.Value = Empty Or TxtConsumo.Value = Empty Then

        MsgBox ("Preencha todos os dados!")
Else
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CADASTRO").Cells(Linha, 8).Value = TxtMes.Value
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CADASTRO").Cells(Linha, 9).Value = TxtAno.Value
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CADASTRO").Cells(Linha, 11).Value = TxtLeitura.Value
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CADASTRO").Cells(Linha, 14).Value = TxtConsumo.Value
End If


End Sub
```

Acredito que seja por causa da seguinte linhas:

```
**Do Until ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CADASTRO").Cells(Linha, 8).Value = Empty
        Linha = Linha + 1**
```

Mas como alterar para parar o preenchimento na linha 90 ? (Começa na linha 85 e quero parar na 90)

Answer (score 0):

Você pode adicionar uma condicional se para sair da função caso passe da linha 90.

#### Código

Com o seguinte código:

```
'Verifica se a Linha é maior do que 90
If Linha > 90 Then
    MsgBox "Você não pode mais inserir cadastros. Mensagem de aviso!"
    Exit Sub
End If
```

#### Código Completo

```
Dim Linha As Long

'Valor inicial da Variável Linha
Linha = 85

Do Until ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CADASTRO").Cells(Linha, 8).Value = Empty
    Linha = Linha + 1
Loop
'Verifica se a Linha é maior do que 90
If Linha > 90 Then
    MsgBox "Você não pode mais inserir cadastros. Mensagem de aviso!"
    Exit Sub
End If

'SE o usuário não entrar com os dados
If TxtMes.Value = Empty Or TxtAno.Value = Empty Then
ElseIf TxtLeitura.Value = Empty Or TxtConsumo.Value = Empty Then

    MsgBox ("Preencha todos os dados!")
Else
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CADASTRO").Cells(Linha, 8).Value = TxtMes.Value
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CADASTRO").Cells(Linha, 9).Value = TxtAno.Value
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CADASTRO").Cells(Linha, 11).Value = TxtLeitura.Value
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CADASTRO").Cells(Linha, 14).Value = TxtConsumo.Value
End If
```